# How do I remove flickering line when using css tranform:scale?

Tags: css, css-animations, flicker

I've been trying to remove this ugly flicker when hovering over the images. I've tried adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the hover element along with the :hover itself but can't seem to shake it. Seems the promblem is only on Chrome and Safari. 
website: http://best-law-firm-sites.com/lawpromo12/

```css
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
}
.panel-wrap {
    height: 100% !important;
}
.panel-wrap .col-sm-4 {
    padding: 0;
}
.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
}
.hovereffect .overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hovereffect h2,
.hovereffect img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hovereffect img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform:  scale(1.001);
    -ms-transform:  scale(1.001);
    -moz-transform:  scale(1.001);
    -o-transform:  scale(1.001);
    transform:  scale(1.001);
}
.hovereffect:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.17);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.17);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.17);
    -o-transform: scale(1.17);
    transform: scale(1.17);
}
.hovereffect h2 {
    bottom: 10%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 17px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.hovereffect h2::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 4px;
    width: 75px;
    background: #BCA474;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.hovereffect a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 70px;
}
.hovereffect:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 panel-1">   
<div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://best-law-firm-sites.com/lawpromo12/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/panel1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Family Law</h2>
           <a class="info" href="services/family-law/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 panel-2">   
<div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://best-law-firm-sites.com/lawpromo12/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/panel.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Estate Planning</h2>
           <a class="info" href="services/estate-planning/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 panel-2">   
<div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://best-law-firm-sites.com/lawpromo12/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/panel.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Wills & Trusts</h2>
           <a class="info" href="services/wills-trusts/"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tested this in Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10 and can't recreate this
... What browser / OS combination are you testing on?

Comment: I can't see the flicker you are referring to, are you using an older OS/Browser?

Comment: I see a strange line in Chrome on Windows 7 when viewing the snippet in stack overflow but not on the demo site you linked to.

Comment: It would be nice to clean up the sample case: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similarly strange behavior in the past when using the backface visibility hack to trick the browser into using the 3d pipeline. There are other ways to 'trick' the browser into using the 3d pipeline like:

```
.class{
    transform: translate3d(0,0,1);
}
```

Comment: Why should it be a comment?

Comment: I recreated the problem, as indicated in the comment I left. 'You might try' is a good answer because it has solved this problem for me in the past.

Comment: When the original question is in the form 'Im doing this hacky undefined thing', it's hard to answer with 'I am certain this other hack will not exhibit the same undefined behavior'

Comment: That doesn't help anyone else coming to this page and skimming to find the answer, which is the entire point of StackOverflow.

Comment: What browser did you re-create this on? I've tried a bunch on multiple machines and have not re-created this.

Comment: See my original comment on the question; Chrome 48.0.2564.109 on Windows 7 running under Windows Classic theme (this might be the kicker)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by increasing the `transform` scale property to 1.001:

```
.hovereffect img{transform: scale(1.001);}
```